# How can i add double quotes to a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add double quotes for a sting . I know by using /" we can add double quotes . My string is

```
string scrip = "$(function () {$(\"[src='" + names[i, 0] + "']\"" + ").pinit();});";
```

When i do this on the browser i am getting &quot instead of " quotes . How can i overcome with the problem ?

Comment: You can mix with single and doule quotes. Use inside of string single and quote whole string with double or vice versa.

Comment: How do you emit this string into the HTML? i.e. What does your ASPX page do with `scrip`?

Comment: @RB I am creating javascript dynamically . Above i am passing image url to that javascript  . but the problem is i should get function     $("[src='/pinterest/portals/0/Images/about-us-group.jpg']").pinit(); but i am getting it as $(&quot;[src='/pinterest/portals/0/Images/about-us-group.jpg']&quot;).pinit();

Answer (score 1):

If your browser has displayed a "&quot" instead of a " character, than there are only a few causes possible. The character should have been emitted to the browser as either itself, or as a *HTML entity* of `&quot;`. Please note the semicolor at the end. If a browser sees such 'code', it presents a quote. This is to allow writing the HTML easier, when its attribtues need to contain special characters, compare:

```
<div attribute="blahblahblah" />
```

if you want to put a " into the blahs, it'd terminate the attribute's notation, and the HTML code would break. So, adding a single " character should look like:

```
<div attribute="blah&quote;blahblah" />
```

Now, if you miss the semicolon, the browser will display `blah&quotblahblah` instead of `blah"blahblah`.

I've just noted that your code is actually glueing up the JavaScript code. In JavaScript, the semicolon is an expression delimiter, so probably there is actually a `&quot;` in the emitted HTML and it is just improperly presented in the error message... Or maybe you have forgotten to open/close some quotes in the javascript, and the semicolon is actually treated as expression terminator?

Be also sure to check why the JavaScript code undergoes html-entity translation. Usually,  blocks are not reparsed. Are you setting that JavaScript code as a HTML element attribute? like OnClick or OnSend? Then stop doing it now. Create a javascript-function with this code and call that function from the click/send instead.. It is not worth to encode long expressions in the JS into an attribute! Just a waste of time and nerves.

If all else fails and if the JavaScript is emitted correctly, then look for any text-correcting or text-highlighting or text-formatting modules you have on your site. Quite probable that one of them is mis-reading the html entities and removed the semicolon, or the opposite - that they add them were they are not needed. The ASP.Net itself in general does its job right, and it translates the entites correctly wherever they are needed, so I'd look at the other libraries first.

Comment: If i use &quote in string i am not getting " quotes , i am getting &amp;quote;

Comment: Its &quote; <- with semicolon. But look at your code: `"$(function () {$(\"[src='" + names`. The output JavaScript is: `$(function () {$("[src='` and here goes the name "pasted". What if the NAME contains a " character? It will break the javascript, for example: `$(function () {$("[src='A cat called "Wrinkle" by friends']"` - see? the `"W` will be treated as a terminator for the string opened earlier at `("[src`. If you want to glue up the javascript code yourself, you have to properly encode all parameters to match the code! In this case, replace all " with \" in the strings and retry.

Comment: string str = "Example String " + "\"" + "This is the String with double quotes." + "\"";I tried for this string also i am getting same problem

Comment: This is incorrect. You are \ing the " but just once. The STR variable will thus hold `example string "this is the string with double quotes"`. If you add it directly to the JS code, then your JS will look like this: `$(function () {$("[src='example string "this is the string with double quotes"']"`. Do you see the no-difference? I still see an ill-formatted JS code.You must add as many layers of escaping, as many layers the string will be passed through. Try with this one: `string str = "A cat called \\\"Wrinkle\\\" by friends";`. Note the additional \\ that will appear in JS code as single \.

Comment: No differnce , i used string str = "A cat called \\\"Wrinkle\\\" by friends"; . But i am getting all 3 \\\ follwed by " .

Comment: Sorry, but either you are kidding, or you have something really screwed up outside of the lines you are trying to fix. With the `string str = "A cat called \\\"Wrinkle\\\" by friends";` you **cannot** see a three-slash output, because C#'s string encoding will squash the slashes to a slash and a quote inside a string variable. The str is `A cat called \"Wrinkle\" by friends` that is safe to be concatenated to yours JS code.. Are you using `string str = @"blarh";` notation? Then a single slash would be sufficient.

Comment: Or maybe, tell me where did you get them? Are you telling me that you saw the three slashes in the debugger? Then everything is correct.. try running the app and see what has been emitted to the HTML code..

Comment: sorry boss . I am not kidding .I am struck with this problem . In html code i am getting \&quot; .

Comment: Ok.. single slash and '&quot;' indicates that the string containing the JS code is being built properly. There's "just" a problem with html entities being applied to it. Could you tell me where do you use the JS code that you have build up from the strings? Are you using it in a <script> block, or are you setting it as some onclick/onsubmit handler?

Comment: I refer now to the "Be also sure" from my answer. If you assign such string to some onclick/onload/onsubmit etc **attribtues**, then it will undergo the transformation to html entities and it may seem to damage the code, but the browser is smart enough to read it properly from attributes, and the code should run properly. You may try to write the same string to a <script> block, there it should not be any html-entity transformation, and you can review if it is all, and/or wrap it into a small function, and use the function in the onclick/onload/etc handler.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are emitting it in <script> block already, then the case will be much harder to diagnose "by chat"..

Comment: Sorry, a correction, I've just found an info that ASP also translates the text in script blocks.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749001/escaping-html-entities-in-javascript-string-literals-within-the-script-block for solution. You have to use slash-codes instead of &quot; and literal ". Such code will be kept as the code itself and it will be embedded in the JS string still as the code, and it will be the JS that will translate the code into a quotation mark.. I'm really surprised. I was sure the ASP does not encode <script> block contents..

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
String str=@"hello,,?!"
```

This should escape all characters
Or

```
String TestString = "This is a <Test String>.";
String EncodedString = Server.HtmlEncode(TestString);
```

Here's the manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What else are you doing with the string?

Seems that somewhere after that the string gets encoded. You can could use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str); but first you'll have to figure out where your string gets encoded in the first place.

Keep in mind that if you use `<%: %>` in aspx or `@yourvar`in Razor it will get encoded automatically. You'll have to use `@Html.Raw(yourvar)` to suppress that.