# Variable String that crashes Browser

Tags: javascript, browser

I found something very strange. When you place something like this in your html page, the browser (tested on FF and Chrome) just stops rendering the page at this place:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // var Crash = "<!--<SCRIPT>";
        </script>
```

Obviously you can also do:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var Crash = "<!--<SCRIPT>";
        </script>
```

Or:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
         var Crash = "<!-- WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE <SCRIPT>";
        </script>
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: This is because `<!--` is used to comment in HTML but it's never close so anything after it will be used as a comment. If you add another script tag but use `var Crash = "WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE <SCRIPT>-->";` further down the page you will see that ends the comment and anything after that will show in the browser.

Comment: When you just do that, then page still works. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/7td2nqcp/1/ . Keep in mind, browser really stops exactly there with whatever he was doing. So it's really nasty.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm saying. `<!--` will comment out any text/html/data until closed using `-->` See https://jsfiddle.net/7td2nqcp/2/ and https://jsfiddle.net/7td2nqcp/3/

Comment: Interesting one.  I'm aware that you can't use the literal string `"</script>"` inside a script block as the browser parser will see that as the end of the script block.  It seems that a combination of the start of a comment and the `<script>` tag causes issues too.  Will need to dig through the specs to find out why.

Comment: @NewToJS It's not the comment by itself though, or the presence of the `<script>` tag - it's the combination of both that is triggering some behaviour

Comment: @JamesThorpe I see what you mean, I have just tried a few other tags, strange one.

Comment: @NewToJS When you just have var Crash = "<!--"; the browser will still load the page. I know what you are saying, but you don't get the interesting part -> the browser hangs completly when having this exact combination: "<!--<SCRIPT>";

Comment: @JamesThorpe btw, having "</SCRIPT>" in the script section is also not same behavior. It still renders stuff that is coming afterwards. But with "<!--<SCRIPT>" the browser stops exactly there and doesn't render anything else.

Comment: @SimonSiegenthaler Oh yes, wasn't saying it was the same issue - just saying that I'm aware that there are other strings that you can't have.  I'm in the relevant part of the spec now, just trying to follow it through (it jumps about a lot)

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR:

Don't do this - it makes the parser follow some strange rules about double escaping script data, leaving it in the "wrong" state (from your point of view) by the time it gets to `</script>`.  There are [ways of escaping things in your script data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749001/escaping-html-entities-in-javascript-string-literals-within-the-script-block) to ensure it will behave as you want it to, while not breaking the parser.

---

The parser has a strict set of rules it follows when parsing the page.  In this case:

- We start, having seen the opening `<script>` tag , in the:
  [Script data state](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/tokenization.html#script-data-state).
- In this stage, `<` triggers:
  [Script data less-than sign state](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/tokenization.html#script-data-less-than-sign-state)
- then, `!` triggers:
  [Script data escape start state](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/tokenization.html#script-data-escape-start-state)
- then, `-` triggers:
  [Script data escape start dash state](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/tokenization.html#script-data-escape-start-dash-state)
- then, `-` triggers:
  [Script data escaped dash dash state](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/tokenization.html#script-data-escaped-dash-dash-state)
- then, `<` (immediately, or while in the "script data escaped state") triggers:
  [Script data escaped less-than sign state](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/tokenization.html#script-data-escaped-less-than-sign-state)
- then, any a-z or A-Z (ie the "S" in "SCRIPT") get stored in the "temporary buffer", and we move to:
  [Script data double escape start state](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/tokenization.html#script-data-double-escape-start-state).  We stay in this state until the end of `script`, then `>` with the combination of the temporary buffer being equal to "script" triggers:
  [Script data double escaped state](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/tokenization.html#script-data-double-escaped-state)
- This just keeps emitting the characters (in your case) until we get to the `<` of `</script>`, which triggers:
  [Script data double escaped less-than sign state](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/tokenization.html#script-data-double-escaped-less-than-sign-state)
- The `/` in `</script>` then clears the temporary buffer, and we switch to:
  [Script data double escape end state](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/tokenization.html#script-data-double-escape-end-state).  This again keeps appending characters to the temporary buffer, until we see the `>`, at which point the temporary buffer is equal to "script", which triggers us to:
  [Script data escaped state](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/tokenization.html#script-data-escaped-state)

So we're now in a state where the browser thinks it's still within some escaped script data, rather than the original `<script>` tag having been closed, so any further HTML is not seen as such - it still thinks it's script data to be handed to the scripting engine rather than processed as HTML.

The reasons for the parser working this way aren't clear, but with the way things have evolved over time, it's probably because of some horrendous backwards compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 3):

In the past, it was common to handle the browsers unaware of the script tag, by adding html comments within the script blocks:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
   // code here
//-->
</script>
```

As you can see the first `<!--` is not valid in javascript, but still the browsers have to ignore it in order to be compatible with this old trick. 
This seems to trigger a weird behaviour in some browser when we add a `<script>`, as you can see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bjeLh5Ln/

So you need either to close the html comment by adding `// -->` in your script, or put `</script>` twice.

Comment: This looks like a lot of fun!