# Set contents of <script> in React serverside component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have this component:

```
export class Demo extends React.Component<DemoProps, any> {
    private foo: number;

    constructor(props: DemoProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <html>
            <head>

                <script>
                   // I would like to add an inline script here
                </script>

            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="root">
                (hello world)
            </div>
            <div>
                <progress id="hot-reload-progress-bar" value="100" max="100"></progress>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
        )
    }
}
```

how can I add an inline script inside the `<script></script>` tags?

If try this:

```
     getScript() {

        const config = JSON.stringify({
            env: process.env.NODE_ENV
        });

        return 'define(\"@config\", [], function () {' +
            ' return ' + config +';' +
            '});'
       }


       <head>
          <script>{this.getScript()} </script>
       </head>
```

I get this on the front end:

```
<html><head><script data-main="/js/main" src="/vendor/require.js"></script><script>define(&quot;@config&quot;, [], function () { return {&quot;env&quot;:&quot;local&quot;};}); </script></head><div><progress id="hot-reload-progress-bar" value="100" max="100"></progress></div><body><div id="root">Initial Home Page</div></body></html>
```

The browser cannot parse this because I get the: `&quot;` characters instead of `"` or `'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do is probably use React's inborn facility - `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` - please see this link to the React docs:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

**Read the docs first**! then look at my solution below.

*The only way I got this feature working was with the following:*

```
export class Demo extends React.Component<DemoProps, any> {

    constructor(props: DemoProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    getScript() {   // return a string representing JS code

        const config = JSON.stringify({
            env: process.env.NODE_ENV
        });

         // return a plain JS object with the __html property
         // set to the string

        return {__html:'define("@config", [], function () {' +
            ' return ' + config +';' +
            '});'}
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <html>

            <head>
                <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getScript()}/>
            </head>

            <body>
            <div id="root">
            </div>

            </body>
            </html>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would satisfy your needs, but you could put your script contents inside a component method and then call the method from within the jsx

```
export class Demo extends React.Component<DemoProps, any> {
    private foo: number;

    constructor(props: DemoProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    scriptContents(){
    //contents of the script in here
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <html>
            <head>

                <script>
                   {this.scriptContents()}
                </script>

            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="root">
                (hello world)
            </div>
            <div>
                <progress id="hot-reload-progress-bar" value="100" max="100"></progress>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: that will probably work, let me try it, I imagine this.scriptContents would just return a string

Comment: thanks this is close, however when I try your methodology for some reason the quote or apostrophe characters don't get sent to the browser correctly, do you know how I could escape them somehow? Probably could look this up somewhere.

Comment: I think this might be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749001/escaping-html-entities-in-javascript-string-literals-within-the-script-block

Comment: this.scriptContents could be just whatever JavaScript you wanted executed at that point

Comment: using React's dangerouslySetInnerHTML was the only way to easily get this working, so I added an answer, even though I think yours is mostly right